# Understanding how data-dismiss attribute works in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm facing a problem with this example:

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

As per my understanding the `data-dismiss="modal"` attribute should close the modal if you click on it, but I don't understand how it works behind the scene. I checked the official documentation at: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples but there's no explanation.

Comment: I think $("#myModal").modal('hide'); is happening behind the scene. Not exactly sure

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The hiding functionality is implemented in the `modal.js` in this way.

```
this.$element.on('click.dismiss.bs.modal', '[data-dismiss="modal"]', $.proxy(this.hide, this))
```

Basically it's just finding the elements that have the attribute of `data-dismiss` and the value of `modal`. Upon click it will hide these elements.

Comment: Could you explain how Bootstrap detect data-dismiss="modal" property on HTML page ? and why does Bootstrap trigger the code that you mentioned ? Sorry for the very basic questions, i'm totally new to the framework.

Comment: @Adeel could you elaborate? If the code searches for a DOM element with attribute `data-dismiss` with value `modal`, it will find my button. How does it determine which DOM node to hide?

Comment: does ```data-dismiss = modal``` removes data inside modal body on close ?

Answer (score 19):

Replace `data-dismiss="modal"` by: `onclick="$('#modal_id').modal('hide');"`

You should have something like this:

```
<button type="button" class="close" onclick="$('#modal_id').modal('hide');" aria-label="Close">
```

`onclick="$('#modal_id').modal('hide');"` will close only the particular modal in which it is placed.

Answer (score 7):

If you use multiple modals on one page open at the same time on top of each other dismissing the topmost with `data-dismiss="modal"` will hide all active modals.

Comment: so how to prevent hidding all other modals

Answer (score 4):

Exactly in `bootstrap.js` find the element with attribute `data-dismiss="modal"` and trigger `this.$element.on('click.dismiss.bs.modal', '[data-dismiss="modal"]', $.proxy(this.hide, this))` behind. i.e. it hides the element but in more complex way.

Comment: That doesn't really explain how bootstrap identifies which object is the modal..

Comment: @naught101 You should have only one modal displayed, multiple modals displayed at the same time is not recommended, use "card" class instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is roughly equivalent to `onclick="$(this).closest('.modal').modal('hide')"`, i.e. it is searching the DOM upward for `.modal` (means, the definition of dialog itself) and hides it. The dialog's DOM is not removed.

Answer (score 0):

I triggered the data dismiss with JQuery like so

```
$('.close').click();
```

This triggered like if user would of clicked the close button on modal, making data-dismiss hit. You might run in to some issues if there is layers of modals at one, hence will close all.

reference to where I found my solution [here](https://www.folkstalk.com/2022/09/data-dismissmodal-in-js-with-code-examples.html)