# How to remove #/modal-about from url

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

This is followup question to this one [Understanding how data-dismiss attribute works in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627271/understanding-how-data-dismiss-attribute-works-in-bootstrap).

We have the exact same implementation using code like this in the layout page:

```html
<!-- about modal -->
    <div id="modal-about" class="modal fade" ng-controller="aboutController">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" 
                            data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">@Labels.aboutTitle</h4>
                </div>
```

If I have some other page opened while opening about form and then closing it, everything is OK. But if I just start my application and go to About menu and open it and close I have the modal-about still in the URL after closing it. The question is - how to hook up into the data-dismiss="modal" to remove that from URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to make use of the `hidden.bs.modal` event and update the URL there:

```
$('#modal-about').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    window.location.hash = '';
});
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/hash

Comment: It works, but I would need to adjust this solution. I only need to do that change if the url ends with modal-about. In other words, if I have another page opened and then open the model and close, it removes the end of my URL which is valid.

Comment: You could use `String.replace` instead: `window.location.hash = window.location.hash.replace('modal-about', '')`

Comment: Good idea. I added a check for endswith and did a replacement only in that case.