# Bootstrap Alert Close

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

my alert starts with 'hide' and then if it has to appear, I add 'show' and I would like to know how to click on the 'x' to alert it not to completely delete the element, just hidden.

```
<div id="alertF" class="alert alert-danger hide show" role="alert">
    <span>Message</span>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding how data-dismiss attribute works in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627271/understanding-how-data-dismiss-attribute-works-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

firstly when you add class `show` than please replace it with class `hide`.--
Don't place both classes at the same time because it create disfunction to your process alert..

×-it works by   button attribute **data-dismiss="alert"**