# Bootstrap 4 modals get all input fields erased once closed

Tags: .net-core, bootstrap-4, razor-pages

Whenever I open a bootstrap modal, close it and open it once again, all of the input fields get erased (textbox, hidden fields, everything)!
Obviously this causes a lot of troubles (first of all the antiforgery token, stored in an hiddenfield, that if missing doesn't allow me to call any page handler or API method where it is required).

I couldn't find anything about this weird behaviour (except for a "hidden.bs.modal" method that could be overridden, but of which I couldn't find any implementation in our code).

This is what I can see from the developer console:

1. First time I open the modal:

[image: First time I open the modal]

[image: First console]

2. Second time I open the modal:

[image: Second time I open the modal]

[image: Second console]

As you can see in the last photo, the antiforgery token value is gone, and even more funny, the value of the input field "destinatariMain" is filled but the form doesn't show anything.

Any tip?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was not Bootstrap nor JQuery fault..
I found this piece of code:

```
$('[data-dismiss=modal]').on('click', function (e) {
    var $t = $(this),
        target = $t[0].href || $t.data("target") || $t.parents('.modal') || [];

    $(target)
        .find("input,textarea,select")
        .val('')
        .end()
        .find("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]")
        .prop("checked", "")
        .end();
})
```

The key part is related to the Jquery selector "[data-dismiss=modal]" that seems related to bootstrap.
Here you can find something about it.

[Understanding how data-dismiss attribute works in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627271/understanding-how-data-dismiss-attribute-works-in-bootstrap)